# Is it possible to change the text of a label in another form without using .Show() or .ShowDialog

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem on **Vb.net**

My question is if it is possible to change the text of a Label without using `frm.Show ()` or `.ShowDialog()`.

Example :

```
frmMain As frmMain = New frmMain
frmMain.lblText.Text = "Hello please help"
```

without using a `.Show()` since it is already shown in a panel :

Comment: Yes it is possible,  If it is showing somewhere use *that* object reference rather than creating a new one. Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Please Plutonix can you please show me an example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

What Plutonix said in the comment, I guess is use the label in another form which already exists instead of making a new one.

For example, add a `label1` in `NewForm1` while designing the form.

Then, in `Form1`, you can do this:

```
NewForm1.label1.text = "Your text here"
```

Otherwise, if you don't want to put a label already in the design time, 
you can add it like this:

```
  Dim NewLabel1 As New Label
    With NewLabel1
        'add properties here
        .Text = "your text"
        .Parent = Me  'set the parent of the label as new form
        .Location = New Point(1, 1)
        'other properties here
    End With
```

Comment: Hello Subaz, Thanks for your help but a question is that possible that i should change the text of another form which is already shown  ? Thanks

Comment: Please i found it so difficult

Comment: I have also adopted a native and stupid method , using a timer, a progressbar, Using it to refresh the frm and things seems working fine But please SIR tell me is that a good WAy ?? Thanks more

Comment: **text of another form?**  are you sure you meant to say form?

Comment: i use it with My.Setiings.lblText = "Text "

Comment: On timer1_timer_tick ; i use lblText.text =  My.Setiings.lblText